# Filtrar data em formato pt-br no AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

Estou com um probleminha para fazer um filtro em AngularJs em um campo de data.

Abaixo segue o html:

```
<td class="text-center" title="'Data'" filter="{ dataProposta: 'text'}" id="'data'">
    {{p.dataProposta | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}
</td>
```

A view fica da seguinte maneira:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No `input` de data ao digitar a data no formato brasileiro **24/03/2016**, o sistema não faz o filtro, porém se eu digitar **2016-03-24**, consigo ver os filtros feito para esta data.

Comment: E o nde está o código que faz o filtro?

Comment: Opa amigo. Acabei tendo que sair do trabalho e vi hoje teu comentário. Mas o que o amigo abaixo respondeu me ajudou aqui. De qualquer forma obrigado também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que fazer um filtro customizado, e testar o texto no formato que está na sua tela, porque, o que está vindo é em outro formato e por isso não funciona.

***Exemplo:***

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.search = '';
  $scope.list = [{
      id: 1,
      data: '2016-01-01'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      data: '2016-01-02'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      data: '2016-01-03'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      data: '2016-01-03'
    },
  ];
  $scope.listFilter = function(model) {
    if ($scope.search === '') return true;    
    var _data = model.data.split('-').reverse();
    _data = _data.join('/');
    return _data.indexOf($scope.search) !== -1;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.7.2/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in list | filter:listFilter">{{d.id}} - {{d.data | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Bom dia. Obrigado, me ajudou bastante aqui.